# Excel macro delete row with consecutive duplicate column data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a complete novice at macro programming in excel. I have an excel file with over 1000 lines of data and would like to delete the entire row when the data in column 44 is repeated in consecutive rows. I've attached the script that I've been trying to tweak to no avail. 
Currently the script deletes most of the duplicate rows but  not all and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub deleteDupes()
  Dim i As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 44).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 44).Value Then _
        .Rows(i).Delete
Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I quickly tested your code and it seems to be okay. You need to show some test data where duplicate rows are not deleted resp. not all of them.

Comment: What rows are not being handled as you expect? Example, please...

Comment: The code looks alright to delete the consecutive duplicate data but not for a complete set of data. I suspect that you have had some duplicate data which are not consecutively stored. Try sorting the column 44 before running the code and check the result.

Comment: Maybe try utilize RemoveDuplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the rows all at once rather than at each line. You can use the [UNION method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to accomplish this. This WILL successfully do what you are describing. If you have issues it has to do with your data.

More importantly, this will make your procedure one **MUCH** faster.

```
Sub deleteDupes()
  Dim i As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim killRng As Range

Set killRng = Rows(Rows.Count)

For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 44).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 44).Value Then _
        Set killRng = Union(Rows(i), killRng)
Next i
End With

    killRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```